# How to incorporate zlibwapi into a ruby project on Windows server?

Tags: ruby, windows, zlib

I've inherited a ruby project on a Windows 10 server that compresses and encrypts files to backup using zlib.

Some of the larger files are returning the data error "string size too big".

I suspect this is a 32bit issue and see there is zlibwapi available that's 64bit however I've not been able to figure out how to incorporate it.

Simply trying to require the file gives "cannot load such file" error and swapping zlibwapi for zlib1 in ruby's bin folder triggers an error with zlib.so.

I'm entirely new to ruby and would appreciate any advice in how to go about this.

**Edit:** This is the specific line from traceback:

```
compressed_data = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(data)
```

And the exact error messages:

```
deflate: string size too big (ArgumentError)
deflate: data error (Zlib::DataError)
```

Comment: "string size too big" is not an error that zlib returns. It must be whatever code is using zlib.

Comment: Thank you; I've edited to include the specific line from traceback and the exact error messages

Comment: What is the size of these "some of the larger files"?

Comment: The one I'm testing against is 2gb

Comment: Exactly 2147483648 bytes?

Comment: Exactly 2,008,815 KB

Comment: That should work. Anyway, strings in Ruby on Windows are limited to 2,147,483,647 bytes in length. You are somehow running into that length limit for a slightly shorter string.

Comment: What's more important is that if you're reading multi-GB files entirely into memory, then you're doing it wrong. You will eventually be thrashing virtual memory, vastly slowing down your application. You need to read a chunk, compress the chunk, write the compressed data, repeat. The chunk size should be in 10's to 100's of K. _Not_ GBs. See the "custom compression" example in the [deflate documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Zlib/Deflate.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve by slicing the string into chunks and iterating over those to deflate the overall string:

```
compressed_data = String.new
z = Zlib::Deflate.new
data.each_char.each_slice(1024) do |chunk|
    compressed_data << z.deflate(chunk.join, Zlib::SYNC_FLUSH)
end
z.finish
z.close
```

Similarly to inflate:

```
data = String.new
z = Zlib::Inflate.new
begin
    compressed_data.each_char.each_slice(1024) do |chunk|
        data << z.inflate(chunk.join)
    end
rescue Zlib::DataError => e
    puts "Error: #{e.message}"
    return nil
ensure
    z.close
end

if data.nil?
    puts "Failed to inflate the data"
end
```

Initially when testing inflate I hit a buffer error when finalizing; the block above however did work.